# I can't figure out on how to use useContext in my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I want to start this question by informing you that I am a total noob in React, but I want to learn how to use it.

I have a back-end for the login page written in Nodejs in which I return some data in case that the username and password entered by the client have a match in the MySQL db. If they are correct I'm sending a JSON to the front-end which contains a JWT sign token, an isAdmin variable (which is a value represented by a 1 or a 0 for every user stored in a column in the database). I want to save that value when I am making the request from the front-end code of the login page, to use it in other React pages to do some conditional rendering of buttons based on the value of isAdmin.

login back-end code:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const { username, pass } = req.body;
    sqlLoginuser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?"
    db.query(sqlLoginuser, [username], (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        if (results.length === 0) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "Username or password is incorrect" });
        }

        const user = results[0];

        bcrypt.compare(pass, user.pass, (error, result) => {
            if (error) throw error;

            if (!result) {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: "Username or password is incorrect" });
            }

            const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1h" });
            console.log(user.is_admin);
            res.status(200).json({
                token,
                isAdmin: user.is_admin,
                message: "User logged in successfully",
            });
        });
    }
    );
});
```

Login.jsx page:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext";

const Login = () => {

    const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(0);
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [pass, setPass] = useState("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const {username: contextUsername} = useContext(AuthContext);

    
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/login", {
                username,
                pass
            });
                toast.success("Te-ai logat cu succes")
                localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
                setIsAdmin(response.data.isAdmin)
                // console.log(isAdmin)
                navigate("/ip");
                setTimeout(() => { window.location.reload() }, 10000);
        } catch (error) {
                toast.error(error.response.data.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ username: contextUsername, isAdmin}}>
            <div style={{ marginTop: "150px" }}>
                <form style={{
                    margin: "auto",
                    padding: "15px",
                    maxWidth: "400px",
                    alignContent: "center"
                }}
                    onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="username"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            value={username}
                            onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            id="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            value={pass}
                            onChange={(event) => setPass(event.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value={"Login"} />
                    <Link to="/register">
                        <input type="button" value="Fa-ti cont" />
                    </Link>
                </form>
            </div>
            </AuthContext.Provider>

    );
};

export default Login;
```

Example of a page that I want to use the value of isAdmin in:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './home.css';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import axios from 'axios';
import {AuthContext} from './AuthContext';


const IP = () => {

    const isAdmin = useContext(AuthContext);
    // console.log(isAdmin.isAdmin)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(0);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(1);

    const itemsPerPage = 10;

    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        // Make a request to the backend to extract the information and store it in a text file
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/extract-ip")
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    throw new Error("Failed to extract data!");
                }
                const data = response.data;
                const file = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.download = 'ip.txt';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    };
    // code for fetching the users from the node.js backend to bring them to the frontend

    const loadData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/ip?page=${currentPage}`);
        setData(response.data.data);
        setTotalPages(response.data.totalPages);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    });

    const deleteIp = (id) => {
        if (
            window.confirm("Stergeti intrarea?")
        ) {
            axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/delete-ip/${id}`)
            toast.success("Intrare eliminata cu succes!")
            setTimeout(() => loadData(), 500);
        }
    }

    const handlePageClick = (pageNumber) => {
        setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>

            <Link to="/addIp">
                <button className="btn btn-ip">Add IP</button>
            </Link>

            <table className='styled-table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>No.</th>
                        <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>IP address</th>
                        <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Added on</th>
                        <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Added by</th>
                        <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.map((item, index) => {
                        const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
                        const rowNumber = startIndex + index + 1;
                        return (
                            <tr key={item.id}>
                                <th scope="row">{rowNumber}</th>
                                <td>{item.ip_address}</td>
                                <td>{item.creation_date.replace("T", " ").replace("Z", "").replace(".000", "")}</td>
                                <td>{item.published_by}</td>
                                <td>
                                    {isAdmin.isAdmin === "1" ?
                                        <>
                                            <Link to={`/update-ip/${item.id}`}>
                                                <button className="btn btn-edit">Edit</button>
                                            </Link>
                                            <button className="btn btn-delete" onClick={() => deleteIp(item.id)}>Delete</button>
                                            <button className="btn btn-edit" disabled={isLoading} onClick={handleClick}>{isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Extract Data"}</button>
                                        </>
                                        :
                                        <>
                                            <Link to="/addIp">
                                                <button className="btn btn-ip">Add IP</button>
                                            </Link>
                                        </>
                                    }
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div className="pagination">
                <ReactPaginate
                    pageCount={totalPages}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                    marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                    onPageChange={(data) => handlePageClick(data.selected + 1)}
                    containerClassName={"pagination"}
                    activeClassName={"active"}
                />
            </div>
            {/* <Link to="/">
                <button className="btn btn-ip">Back</button>
            </Link> */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default IP;
```

I understand that I have to use useContext to accomplish this.
I created an AuthContext.jsx, which look like this:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  username: "",
  isAdmin: 0,
})
```

This is the App.js file:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'
import './App.css';
import React from "react";
import IP from './pages/ip.jsx';
import Domain from './pages/domain.jsx';
import IOC from './pages/ioc.jsx';
import UpdateIp from './pages/updateIP.jsx'
import UpdateDomain from "./pages/updateDomain.jsx";
import UpdateIoc from "./pages/updateIOC.jsx";
import Navbar from "./pages/navbar";
import Register from "./pages/Register.jsx";
import Login from "./pages/Login.jsx"
import NavbarLoggedin from "./pages/NavbarLogged";
import { AuthContext } from "./pages/AuthContext";

function App() {

    const [ hasToken, setHasToken ] = useState(false)
    useEffect( () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (token) {
            setHasToken(true)
        } else {
            setHasToken(false)
        }
    }, []);

  return (
        <>
            {hasToken ? (
                <>
                <Navbar />
                    <div className="App">
                        <ToastContainer position="top-center" />
                        <Routes>
                            <AuthContext.Provider>
                                <Route path="/" element={<Login/>}/>
                                <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
                                <Route path="/domain" element={<Domain/>}/>
                                <Route path="/ip" element={<IP/>}/>
                                <Route path="/ioc" element={<IOC/>}/>
                                <Route path="/addIp" element={<UpdateIp/>}/>
                                <Route path="/addDomain" element={<UpdateDomain/>}/>
                                <Route path="/addIoc" element={<UpdateIoc/>}/>
                                <Route path="/update-ip/:id" element={<UpdateIp/>}/>
                                <Route path="/update-domain/:id" element={<UpdateDomain/>}/>
                                <Route path="/update-ioc/:id" element={<UpdateIoc/>}/>
                            </AuthContext.Provider>
                        </Routes>
                    </div>
        </>
            ) : (
        <>
                <NavbarLoggedin />
                    <div className="App">
                        <ToastContainer position="top-center" />
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/" element={<Login/>} />
                            <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>} />
                        </Routes>
                    </div>
        </>
            )}
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The above pages of code that I have provided, are working somehow, but the problem is that the value of isAdmin at login is 1, outputed by using console.log() in the backend, but the value of isAdmin in the Login page and IP page is 0.

I don't understand why the value of isAdmin doesn't get updated.

I followed the docs of useContext in the React documentation, but I can't figure this out.

This is starting to get frustrating, please help me or provide me some kind of guidance to resolve this issue.

Comment: Any guidance will be appreciated folks. Thank you in advance.